# Convert serialized() complex string to array of objects

Tags: javascript, json, serialization

I have a string:

```
"id=1&lotcode=ACB&location=A1&id=2&lotcode=CCC&location=B1"
```

Now I want to get an array of objects to pass to controller via ajax like this:

```
[{"id":1, "lotcode"="ACB","location":"A1"},{"id":2, "lotcode"="CCC","location":"B1"}]
```

I started by splitting the string

```
var string = data.split('&', 2);
```

now I stuck here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split the string by `&` and then take the key/value pairs and assign them to an array with an incrementing index.

This solution assumes, that all keys have the same count.

```js
var string = "id=1&lotcode=ACB&location=A1&id=2&lotcode=CCC&location=B1",
    result = [],
    indices = {};

string.split('&').forEach(s => {
    var [key, value] = s.split('='),
        index = (indices[key] || 0);
    
    result[index] = result[index] || {};
    result[index][key] = value;    
    indices[key] = index + 1;
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```